# Intermittent loss of internet connectivity with good wireless signal

Tags: internet, connection

I recently bought a HP touch smart running windows 7. At random times, internet connectivity is lost while the wireless signal remains strong. The only way to restore connectivity is to restart the PC. Nothing else works. Have many other PC's on the same router also running windows 7 and no problems there. Have changed routers and problem remains. I have reinstalled the network drivers with no help. Any thoughts?

Comment: What are your wireless router, network card, running firewalls, and type of security/encryption used?

Comment: Linskys 2000, Ralink n network card, windows firewall, WPA2/AES. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take your laptop in for servicing. It sounds as if you have a bad wireless card.